# Use XSLT 1, 2 or 3 to identify duplicate entries within a file based the combined text of two elements

Tags: xslt

I have an XML table comprised of cases within individual //entry elements. I need to identify if any case is duplicated by combining //field name="partya"/label + //field name="partyb"/label and then using the combined value to search the file for duplicates. I have managed to get the search working based on "partya" using xsl:key, but there are instances where partya is the same but the case is not a duplicate. Would it be best to convert the values to a string and then perform the search or group using xsl:for-each-group? I'm just getting back into xslt after a long break so any help would be most appreciated.

```
<entry xmlns:lcr="http://xml.smg-uk.com/schema/lcr">
         <display>
            <field name="partya">
               <label>Abigail</label>
            </field>
            <field name="partyb">
               <label>Seddon</label>
            </field>
            <field name="validation-type">
               <label>auto-valid</label>
            </field>
          </display>
      </entry>
<entry>
         <display>
            <field name="partya">
               <label>24 Seven Utility Services Ltd</label>
            </field>
            <field name="partyb">
               <label>Rosekey Ltd (t/a Atwasl Builders)</label>
            </field>
            <field name="validation-type">
               <label>manual-valid</label>
            </field>
           </display>
      </entry>
```

Comment: It was a typo, which I've now corrected. Thanks

Comment: Consider to post minimal but complete, representative samples of XML input and wanted result. If you want to use grouping or identify duplicates then perhaps the notes in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xslt-grouping/info help as a starting point, for instance with a composite grouping key in XSLT 3 using `composite="yes" group-by="field[@name = 'partya']/label, field[@name = 'partyb']/label"`.